# sonar scanner quality profile assignment using windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, unix, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I'm trying to assign quality profile to a project created in Sonar qube using a batch script. It was working perfectly fine when using shell script in Unix

```
curl -u <token>: -X POST "http://sonarqube-qa.it.company.net:9000/api/qualityprofiles/add_project?profileName=TEST%E2%80%93MSBI%E2%80%93SSIS&projectName=%project_name%&projectKey=%project_key%&language=xml"
```

Name of quality profile:-

```
TEST-MSBI-SSIS
```

Error message when executing the batch script, which is working fine when executing unix shell script.

```
{"errors":[{"msg":"Quality Profile for language 'xml' and name 'TEST803MSBI803SSIS' does not exist"}]}
```

What is the windows equivalent of `%E2%80%93` to replace '-' as in Unix

Comment: From a batch file, you should double all **`%`** characters, except for those surrounding your variables, `%project_name%` and `%project_key%`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked :-)
I used TEST%%E2%%80%%93MSBI%%E2%%80%%93SSIS.

Comment: @Compo Can you put this in answer so that I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

From a batch file, you should double all **`%`** characters, except for those surrounding your variables, `%project_name%` and `%project_key%`.

For instance:

```bat
curl -u <token>: -X POST "http://sonarqube-qa.it.company.net:9000/api/qualityprofiles/add_project?profileName=TEST%%E2%%80%%93MSBI%%E2%%80%%93SSIS&projectName=%project_name%&projectKey=%project_key%&language=xml"
```